# Image not loading in dynamic page of Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I've done the assets pipeline for my rails project and everything is working fine, except on the dynamic posts page, like *http://localhost:3000/posts/2*, where images doesn't load. Everywhere else it works fine.

In console I get this error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/posts/assets/logo.png")

But I used `src="assets/m1.jpg` in image tag but in the console error the link is different!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image tag has the following exact image path specified:

```
<img src="assets/m1.jpg" etc="etc">
```

...then the browser will treat that as a **relative URL** and try to look it up **relative** to the URL of the current page, which is **`http://localhost:3000/posts/2`**.

As a result, the browser will look for an image with this URL: **`http://localhost:3000/posts/assets/m1.jpg`**, which is exactly what's happening in your case.

Try using the [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper instead:

```
<%= image_tag "m1.jpg" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Links that don't start with a `/` look within the same "folder" you're currently in. Thus when you're on `localhost:3000/posts/2` you're in the `posts` 'folder' and so it looks for `localhost:3000/posts/assets/m1.jpg`.

If your start a link with a `/` it'll look from the top of the current site `localhost:3000`, thus `/assets/m1.jpg` will look for `localhost:3000/assets/m1.jpg` which is where you want it to be looking.

In your code you, can use the [image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper instead of manually writing out your image tags:

```
image_tag('m1.jpg') # <img alt="M1" src="/assets/m1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the helper `<%= image_tag('m1.jpg') %>` and put your image in the `assets/images/` directory.
The helper will generate the correct path to the image